How to Manage HTTP Response Headers in Apache for a Magento Site?
I want to update headers like Cache-Control, Expires, and Pragma, but I'm facing issues even after making changes in my .htaccess file.
Current Configuration:
I've added the following to my .htaccess file:
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header unset Expires
    Header unset Pragma
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive Off
</IfModule>

I expected that after making these changes, the Cache-Control, Expires, and Pragma headers would either be removed entirely or updated to reflect the new values I set in the .htaccess file. Specifically, I was hoping to see:
Cache-Control unset or set to "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
Expires unset or set to "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
Pragma unset or set to "no-cache"
However, despite these efforts, the headers remain unchanged in the response. This has led me to seek further guidance on what might be causing the headers to persist and how I can effectively manage them.

I realized that I am using an Apache server with Magento, where there is typically one .htaccess file for different directories. I am receiving CSS and JS files from the pub/static/ directory, which also contains its own .htaccess file. After changing the configuration in that file, the request headers in my browser are updated. Please ensure that you update the .htaccess file for the correct directory. If you modify the .htaccess file in other directories, such as the Magento installation directory, instead of the directory from which the browser is receiving the data, it won't affect the browser headers (in my scenario). This can save time for others.
